# Laravel polymorphic relation - returns relation

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relation

i want to let users that have bookmarks. it means users can bookmark posts, articles, etc...
so this is my schema 
users 
     id 
bookmarks
    id
    bookmarkable_id
    bookmarkable_type
    user_id
articles
   id
posts
   id
as you can see it is a Polymorphic relation.

well i can add a bookmark for an article and it is okay.
my problem is when i want to get bookmarks of a user. imagine user have 4 posts that bookmarked. he wants to see them.

i wrote a relation for it but it returns []; ( user at least has one bookmarked post)

User.php

```
public function bookmarks()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Bookmark::class, 'bookmarks', 'bookmarkable_type','user_id');
    }
```

it is the result

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#313 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

and this is Bookmark model:

```
 public function bookmarkable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class ,'bookmarkable_id','id');
    }
```

and this is how i try to access the bookmarks:

```
$articles  = auth()->user()->bookmarks;
dd($articles);
```

when i use this for get the bookmarked posts:

```
public function bookmarks()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Bookmark::class,  'user_id','id');
    }
```

it will return the record in the bookmarks table.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information, so I'm assuming that your database schema is like so -

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

articles
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    name - string

bookmarkables
    bookmark_id - integer
    bookmarkable_id - integer
    bookmarkable_type - string
```

Your Post and Article models both need the following relationship -

```
public function bookmarked_by()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'bookmarkable');
}
```

Your User model then needs the following relationships -

```
public function bookmarked_posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'bookmarkable');
}

public function bookmarked_articles()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Article::class, 'bookmarkable');
}
```

You are then able to use `auth()->user()->bookmarked_posts` and `auth()->user()->bookmarked_articles`.